# I want to reset my mac completely but want to have the same ssh keys, How can I do that?

Tags: ssh, mac, macos-catalina, macos-bigsur

my daily work involves ssh tunneling and for that reason I want to keep the same ssh keys. The problem is my mac is giving me terrible issues after I installed big sur few days back. I want to go back to Catalina and delete everything that I have on my mac right now.

I thought of keeping a backup of the .ssh folder and replacing it after reset/update. Will that work? If not, then what can I do?

Comment: Have you backed up the private and public keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it works, If you want to keep the same keys and want to reset your system then take a back up of `~/.ssh` folder and replace it with the new folder that you get after the reset (if it's not there, then create a new folder named .ssh in home directory).

But it won't work straight after pasting, it will give you some error like this:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for '/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa": bad permissions
```

You will have to change the permissions for this, I typed `chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa` which is read-only, if you want read and write then give `600` instead of `400`. It will start working.

Answer (score 1):

I have absolutely no clue about Apple machines or MacOS, but I know that their SSH daemon works nearly identically to OpenSSH, so I'll answer your question.

You will have to take two aspects of the same thing into account:

Backing up your `.ssh` folder is a great idea and will *almost* be enough. In that folder, there usually are *your* SSH keys (private and public), a file called `authorized_keys` (containing the public keys of remote machines / users which are allowed to ssh into your box), and a file called `known_hosts` (containing ids of the remote machines which *you* have ssh'd into in the past).

This is the first pitfall. If you have multiple users on your MAC, there may be multiple `.ssh` directories (usually one per user), and you must back up all of them. This is not uncommon: For example, you may have one user who is only allowed to shut down the system, another user who is allowed to initiate backups, and your own user account. Your UPS system may ssh into your box as `shutdown` user to shut it down if necessary. A centralized backup manager may ssh into your box as `backup` user to initiate a backup - you get the idea :-)

The other side is the *daemon* side: You really should backup the directory which in Linux / OpenSSH usually is `/etc/ssh`. This is the directory where the SSH **daemon** stores its own keys, where the daemon's configuration file resides (usually `sshd_config`), and where (possibly) a system-wide client configuration file exists (usually `ssh_config`).

However, I have no clue where this directory is in MacOS. To find it, you could search for the file names mentioned above, but please make sure that the daemon's keys are in there as well. They usually are stored in files whose names begin with `ssh_host`. It would be also a good idea to save the `moduli` file, which normally has exactly this name.

In summary:

`.ssh` in your (and other users' !) home directory contains files which are needed by the SSH **client** (except authorized_keys). Notably, look for `authorized_keys`, `known_hosts` and the public and private key files, whose names normally are `id_(rsa|ed25519)_...[.pub]`

`/etc/ssh` (or wherever MacOS stores that data) contains files which are needed by the SSH **daemon** (except the system-wide client configuration). Notably, look for `moduli`, `ssh_config`, `sshd_config` and the daemon's key files, whose names normally are `ssh_host_(ecdsa|rsa|ed25519)_key[.pub]`.

Good luck!